# NotePad++ Find text and move to 2nd space from right

Tags: text, move

I have a text file with thousands of lines and what I want to do for each line is to find the string "nnnnn ST" and move it to before the 2nd space from the right.

```
What I have:
xxx xxx xxxxxx 123 ST xxx xxx xxx
xxxxxx xxxxxxx 3 ST xxxxx xxx xxx
xxxxxx 88 ST xx xxx xxx xxx

What I want: 
xxx xxx xxxxxx xxx 123 ST xxx xxx
xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx 3 ST xxx xxx
xxxxxx xx xxx 88 ST xxx xxx
```

The string that I want to move will always be a number, space, and the "ST" and every single line will end with two words.
If anyone can provide some insight in terms of using REGEX, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no regex, but:

When choosing 'start Recording' from the Macro menu, you can record the following steps.

1. Find 'ST'
2. Find ' ' backwards
3. Hit CTRL+SHIFT+RIGHT 2 times
4. Hit CTRL+X
5. Hit 'End'
6. Find ' ' backwards
7. Hit CTRL+V
8. Add a space
9. Hit 'Home', followed by 'Down'

Or edit `%appdata%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`, and make the start of it look like:

```
<NotepadPlus>
    <InternalCommands />
    <Macros>
        <Macro name="nrsST" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
            <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="ST" />
            <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam=" " />
            <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="256" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam=" " />
            <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="256" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1" sParam="" />
            <Action type="0" message="2442" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="0" message="2442" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="0" message="2177" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="0" message="2451" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam=" " />
            <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="256" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam=" " />
            <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="256" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1" sParam="" />
            <Action type="0" message="2179" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam=" " />
            <Action type="0" message="2453" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="0" message="2300" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
        </Macro>
    </Macros>
.....
```

After the edit restart Notepad++, and you should be able to select the macro. (Make sure your cursor is positioned at the start of the document)

Every run of the macro will correct 1 line, so you need to repeat it until done...

[image]

P.S. Make sure you have a backup before editing `shortcuts.xml`, to make sure you can return to your original situation.